# Adding tables to UITextView, whats the best approach?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have been looking into the supported features of UITextView and its accompanying library Core Text. Under MacOSX you have NSTextTable which allows you to add tables to your text only. Sadly enough, this class is not supported under iOS. Now my question is what is the best approach to support this under iOS?

Just want to make a simple table with five columns. If I understood it correctly I might be able to do something by creating custom attributes for NSAttributedString. Only I am not sure what the best approach is? The objective is that I can create a text document with one table which I can export to RTF. For the latter I would need to write my own RTF exporter class that shouldn't be a big problem. As the RTF format is quite well documented on the Internet. My major problem is how to get the table shown in my text view.

Or should I just go for a UIWebView instead?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how you can do multiple columns in a UITableView in an easily manner.

Comment: Assuming you don't want each column to scroll separately, why not make a custom UITableViewCell subclass that contains a single row?

Comment: Aah, I will experiment. Thanks.